# Passing jQuery values as event parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

If there is a value being held in a hidden field, how could I access the value using jQuery in a function being called by an onclick event without having to call another function to do it?  Essentially, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Update($('#hdnID').val())" >
```

Comment: And what isn't working ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gxLgu/

Comment: Assuming your function is defined as `function Update(value) {...}` then you can access the argument via `value`. Learn more about functions: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>Type something and click</p>
<br /><br />
<input type="hidden" id="hdnID" value=123 />
<br /><br />
<a href="#" onclick="Update($('#hdnID').val())" >Click me</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/devjit/a4zBQ/

Its actually adeneo's ans, I only changed it to "hidden" and gave it a value